# how i can get Facebook seesion key and facebook token access from cookies facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i used the facebook cookies fbs_FacebookApplicationKey to get Facebook seesion key and facebook token access
now the facebook name is changed to fbsr_FacebookApplicationKey and i see it is encrypted
how i can get Facebook seesion key and facebook token access from cookies facebook
or from graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, please see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Thank you for reply but I need access token from cookies